# can slot take entity values without a action function or forms in RASA?

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-core

is it possible to pass values in the entity to slots without form or writing an action function?

nlu.yml

```
nlu:
- intent: place_order
  examples: |
    - wanna [large](size) shoes for husky
    - need a [small](size) [green](color) boots for pupps
    - have [blue](color) socks
    - would like to place an order

- lookup: size
  examples: |
    - small
    -medium
    -large

- synonym: small
  examples: |
    - small
    - s
    - tiny
- synonym: large
  examples: |
    - large
    - l
    - big

- lookup: color
  examples: |
    - white
    - red
    - green
```

domain.yml

```
version: "2.0"

intents:
  - greet
  - goodbye
  - affirm
  - deny
  - mood_great
  - mood_unhappy
  - bot_challenge
  - place_order

entities:
  - size
  - color

slot:
  size:
    type: text
  color:
    type: text

responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: "Hey! can I assist you ?"

  utter_order_list:
  - text : "your order is {size} [color} boots. right?"
```

stories.yml

```
version: "2.0"

stories:

- story: place_order
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: utter_greet
  - intent: place_order
  - action: utter_order_list
```

debug output: it recognize entity , but the value is not passed to slot

Hey! can I assist you ?
Your input ->  I would like to place an order for large blue shoes for my puppy

```
 Received user message 'I would like to place an order for large blue shoes for my puppy' with intent '{'id': -2557752933293854887, 'name': 'place_order', 'confidence': 0.9996021389961243}' and entities '[{'entity': 'size', 'start': 35, 'end': 40, 'confidence_entity': 0.9921159148216248, 'value': 'large', 'extractor': 'DIETClassifier'}, {'entity': 'color', 'start': 41, 'end': 45, 'confidence_entity': 0.9969255328178406, 'value': 'blue', 'extractor': 'DIETClassifier'}]'

 Failed to replace placeholders in response 'your order is {size} [color} boots. right?'. Tried to replace 'size' but could not find a value for it. There is no slot with this name nor did you pass the value explicitly when calling the response. Return response without filling the response
```

Answer (score 1):

"slot" is an unknown keyword. you should write "slots" instead of "slot" in the domain file and it will work.